# Can a language extension written in Visual Studio Code be used in Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code

I am writing a language extension in Visual Studio code ([see this article for an example](https://www.codemag.com/Article/1809051/Writing-Your-Own-Debugger-and-Language-Extensions-with-Visual-Studio-Code)), and I wish to know whether this extension will be useable in Visual Studio 2017 (and 2019 when it comes out).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [visual studio docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/adding-an-lsp-extension?view=vs-2017) and especially to [this picture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/adding-an-lsp-extension?view=vs-2017#language-server-protocol) it should be possible to migrate that language server to visual studio, too.
However it is not possible to use the exact same extension for VS Code as well as for Visual Studio. At least you will have to change the *Provider-specific intizialization code* (see the picture) to make the server work for Visual Studio, too.
For further reading you can check out the corresponding VS Code [docu on language server](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/language-server-extension-guide).